# Include properties file in .sql file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script which reads system resource statistics and stores it in mysql database. For this, I have a .sql file which I am using to create the database and tables and keep inserting values into. I want to keep the database authentication data like username ,password , etc. in a separate properties file.

Is there a way to include this properties file in the .sql file and use the variables or do I have to read the props file in the php script itself?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

The .sql file is as follows:

```
/*Create database 'monitoring'*/
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS monitoring;

/*Use database 'monitoring'*/
USE monitoring;

/*Create table 'server_resource_stats'*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS server_resource_stats(id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,server_id INT(3) NOT NULL,time INT(12) NOT NULL,resource VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, measure FLOAT(12,4) NOT NULL, unit VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
```

The portion of php code to perform inserts is:

```
foreach ($requestBody as $json_stat) {
    $arr_stat = json_decode($json_stat, true);

    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO server_resource_stats (server_id,time,resource,measure,unit) VALUES (1," . $arr_stat["time"] . ",". $arr_stat["resource"] . "," . $arr_stat["measure"] . "," . $arr_stat["unit"] . ")";
    if ($mysqli_con->query($sql_query) != TRUE) {
        echo "error inserting into table\n";
    }
```

I want to be able to place the insert queries in the .sql file itself and pass the request body to the file.Is this possible?

Comment: A file of SQL commands can't contain connection and authorization information. You'll have to instruct PHP to do something anyway. So yes, use a php script for configuration.

Comment: After some reading,I realized I cant do that.Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way I can pass parameters(parameters for insert command) to the .sql file?

Comment: Give an example on what you have, what you were trying to do, or which code/approach you tried before. This question is somewhat vague and not answerable otherwise.

Comment: @mario I have added my code.Please take a look at it.Thanks.